# MySQL, Is it possible to have multiple Foreign key values in one table looking at values from a differnt Table?

Tags: mysql

I have two Tables a PC_Build Table that consists of a PcID (primary Key), a FinalCost, and a PartID. I also have a Parts table that has PartID (Primary Key), Part_Name, Cost. Is it possible for my PC_Build to have multiple PartID's, that link to the Parts table??? Also is it possible for me to calculate the cost of the PC_Build, from the sum of the parts that are used in the build by getting the cost from parts, and adding it to the FinalCost variable in PC_Build.

Comment: you need n:m relationship. http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Comment: @Imre Added this link to my answer as it's good info.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It's perfectly allowed. You can have as many foreign keys to the same table as you like as long as the columns and foreign keys are named differently.

However, for the situation you describe, this isn't necessarily a good idea. It breaks [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) and you will have problems if for example a PC has 4 of the same sticks of RAM in it and another has 8 or a PC has 3 CPUs but another has 1. How will you handle that situation? If you use foreign keys you would need to keep changing your table to accommodate all the different situations.

It would probably be better to have a PC_Build_Part table that had two columns, PcID and PartID. Then you could use joins to simply work out what parts belong to which PC.

Here's an example schema:

PC (**PcID**, BuildCost)

Part (**PartID**, PartName, PartCost)

PC_Part(*PcID*, *PartID*)

This is called a [many-to-many relationship](http://tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php).

To calculate the BuildCost column you could do a query like the following:

```
SELECT SUM(p.PartCost) as TotalCost
FROM Part p
JOIN PC_Part pcp ON pcp.PartID = p.PartID
JOIN PC pc ON pc.PcID = pcp.PcID
```

This would allow you to flexibly handle many different PC configurations without having to change your schema.

Comment: So what your saying is, If i just made a column for each part, so lets say for example, a CPU Column, and just give it the part ID, for one of the CPU's in the Parts table. It would break normalization. What your suggesting is have a 3rd table that links PC_Build to PC_Build_Part to Parts. How would I get the costs of the Parts that pertain to the Build of the PC, to add to the Final cost of the PC, would that only be possible in a query?

Comment: No don't make a column for each part. See my example schema.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily need the BuildCost column, you could do that with a query - I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I'll be trying this :)

Comment: Rob describes a many-to-many relationship, and how to implement an association table to represent the relationship. (We call it a many-to-many relationship because a part is related to many pc_builds, and a pc_build is related to many parts.

Comment: Next question, I Followed your example of the PC_Part table, of just the two Id's. Lets say I'm to let someone chose Parts to build a PC, would they be inputting their data into the PC_Part table. ie, Lets say the first pc is PC01, and they are choosing the parts that go into the table would the entry look like INSERT INTO PC_Part VALUES ('PC01','CP01'), ('PC01','VD02'); Where CP01, and VD02, are different parts like a CPU and Video Card.

Comment: Then after that is all said and done, I would then run the query you gave in the example, to get the cost of the PC build :), Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

If every part belongs to a certain PC, then you'll want to add a PcID column to the Parts table and remove the PartID from your PC_Build table. If you have a fixed catalog of parts and each PC can consist of multiple Parts and each part can be used in multiple PCs then you need an additional table (PC_to_Part) where you have a PcID and a PartID.

Yes, assuming the former method, you can find the cost of each PC using a query like

```
SELECT PcID, SUM(Cost)
FROM PC_Build
JOIN Parts ON (Parts.PcID = PC_Build.PcID)
GROUP BY PcID
```

Comment: Thank you :) I'll try this and see if it does the job!!

Comment: In this schema a part could only belong to one PC, this isn't necessarily wrong, just to make that clear.

Comment: How would it be possible for multiple parts linked to one PC. Cause a PC needs a CPU, Motherboard, Power Supply, Ram, etc...  Should I have a table for each type of part linked to a PC table??

Comment: @Rob Uhm, I proposed two different schemas, which one do you mean?

Comment: @Donnie No, not different tables per Part. Just give the CPU, the motherboard and the power supply all the same PcID.